# Can it be replace it with a v-if

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I replace the following code with a `v-if` or is there another way to short the condition in Vue for this code.

```
 <option value="?page=item" {{ current == key ? ' SELECTED' : '' }}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use v-binding on the `selected` attribute:

```html
<option value="?page=item" :selected="current == key">
```

Honestly you should be using `v-model` on your `select` element, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
<v-select :value="?page=item" @input="setSelected" />

methods: {
   setSelected(value) {
     //  trigger a mutation, or dispatch an action  
    var selected = '';
    return selected;

 }
```

}